# img with percent height for spreading width of parent element

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve some layout with percent setting of height on img element , it performed perfect while first loading, but I found that the img element couldn't spreading the parent element when browser resize.

The width of parent element will still be the former width and will not change after resizing.

How can I fix it without js and with pure css?

here are some example code:

```
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
.container{
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  background:yellow;
}
img{
  height:30%;
  width:auto;
}

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOYdZ.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if i understood your question properly but created a codepen script. You can check it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJYBoW). Added a "width:30%" property

```
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
.container{
  float:left;
  background:yellow;
}
img{
  width:30%;
  height:30%;
}
```

Comment: my mistake, I forgot to add height:100% in container's style,you can try to resize browser while the code is runing again